# iOS- Capabilities setting for App Sandbox in Xcode if In App Purchase is used

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have implemented In App Purchase in app. Do I need to turn on App Sandbox in Capabilities of Xcode ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on the "In-App Purchase" switch in your app's capabilities:

[image: In-App Purchase Capabilities]

Answer (score 0):

No you do not, because all iOS apps are sandboxed by default. The App Sandbox capability doesn't even show in Xcode if you're creating an iOS app (see Michael's screenshot).